# Error: unexpected symbol in: " name = page %>% html_nodes(".title"

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am scrapping data using R but it show an error - "Error: unexpected symbol in: "     name = page %>% html_nodes(".title"

```
`email = function(writer_email) {
  page = read_html(writer_email)
  writer_email = page %>% html_node(".field-type-email a") %>% html_text()
  return(writer_email)
}

writerdata = data.frame()

for (page_result in seq(from = 0, to = 20)) {
  link = paste0("https://www.pw.org/directory/writers?genre=All&translated=All&journal-nid=&identity=15969&work=All&language=English&education=All&retreat=All&agent=All&metroarea%5Bcity_autocomplete%5D=&metroarea%5Bhidden_latitude%5D=&metroarea%5Bhidden_longitude%5D=" ,page_result, ")
  page = read_html(link)
  
  name = page %>% html_nodes(".title a") %>% html_text()
  writer_email = page %>% html_nodes(".title a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.pw.org", ., sep = "")
  
  email = sapply(writer_email,function = email, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  
  writerdata = rbind(writerdata, data.frame(name, email, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  
  print(paste("Page:", page_result))
 }`
```

Comment: Correct the link assignment line and email assignment. Think how to terminate string properly within paste0 and the argument names for sapply.

Comment: Greetings! It appears part of the issue may be the data itself or it could very well be the function. Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg